# Deserialize JSON to Collection of Unknown Types

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm writting a program in Java that makes requests to an external API by calling some methods. Each of these methods returns a diferent JSON structure and it also depends on the passed parameters. My question is if there's some way to deserialize the response string using Gson without having to write a different class for each method.

If not Gson, which other library could I use?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My question is if there's some way to deserialize the response string using Gson without having to write a different class for each method.

Yes, there is.  If the JSON structure that you don't care to deserialize into a specific Java type is just an object that contains key-value pairs, where all of the values are JSON primitives, then the structure can be simply deserialized into a `Map<String, String>`.

Note that a `Map<String, Object>` would not work as it does not provide enough type information for Gson to deserialize into.  Gson would just create plain `Object` instances for each value -- not `String` or `Integer` instances, but just plain `Object` instances.  The actual values in the JSON would not be deserialized.  On the surface it seems reasonable that Gson could be enhanced to create more type-specific instances for `JsonPrimitive` values.  For example, since it's possible to determine whether a `JsonPrimitive` is a `Boolean`, with a call to `isBoolean()`, then one might hope Gson would just construct a `Boolean`, but it doesn't -- Gson just creates an empty and probably-useless `Object`.

Here's an example that demonstrates this point.

**input.json Contents:**

```
{
  "one":"won",
  "too":22,
  "3":false
}
```

**Foo.java:**

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.Map;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

public class Foo
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Type mapOfStringObjectType = new TypeToken<Map<String, String>>() {}.getType();
    Map<String, String> map = gson.fromJson(new FileReader("input.json"), mapOfStringObjectType);
    System.out.println(map);
  }
}
```

The output of this example is `{3=false, one=won, too=22}`.

If the `Map` type in the example is changed to `HashMap<String, Object>` as recommended in another answer, then the output becomes `{3=java.lang.Object@10b61fd1, one=java.lang.Object@24e2dae9, too=java.lang.Object@299209ea}`, which is of course probably useless.

If for some reason a type of `HashMap<String, Object>` *must* be deserialized to, then custom deserialization processing would be necessary.

If the JSON structure is not a simple set of key-value pairs, where the values are all JSON primitives, but include values that are complex types like JSON objects, even if it's acceptable to transform all of the values into `Strings`, then it would also be necessary to implement custom deserialization processing.

Don't hesitate to head on over to [the Gson Issues List](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/issues/list) and submit an enhancement request for improved JSON primitive deserialization to appropriately specific Java `Object` types, or to have a simple mechanism to transform any value -- including complex JSON types like objects and arrays -- in a Map into a `String`, such that custom deserialization processing as described above wouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Gson issue 325 addresses simple deserialization to Map<String, Object>.  Please don't hesitate to vote for its implementation at http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/issues/detail?id=325

Comment: Note that Jackson (http://jackson.codehaus.org) can deserialize the example JSON above to a Map<String, Object> without custom processing, and JSON-lib (http://json-lib.sourceforge.net) can similarly deserialize to a Map (Map map = JSONObject.fromObject(json);).

Comment: Note, a previous comment I made on this subject was for a previous version of Gson.  With the implementation of Gson issue 325, it may now work to just deserialize to Map<String, Object>.  I don't know for sure, as I haven't yet try to do so.

Answer (score 1):

You have to write different class which would represent the responses from different methods if you want to use gson. If the response is simple key-value, then you can convert the response into a `HashMap<String,Object>` which will act as a 'generic' class to satisfy all type of responses in your use case.

Comment: Note that HashMap<String, Object> does not include enough type information for Gson to deserialize to.  Gson would just create plain old Object instances for the Map values -- not from subclasses of Object like String or Integer, but just Objects.  I'll post more details in an answer to this question.

Comment: Note, the previous comment I made on this subject was for a previous version of Gson.  With the implementation of Gson issue 325, it may now work to just deserialize to Map<String, Object>.  I don't know for sure, as I haven't yet try to do so.